# Receiving email address through Amazon Connect/Lex?

Tags: amazon-lex, aws-lex, amazon-connect

I'm currently trying to set up a bot to collect email address via Connect/Lex using voice. I know this is near impossible to do without spelling it out character by character. I've tried setting custom slots, using AMAZON.EmailAddress, etc, but all options seem to mishear a lot of characters. Has anyone had any luck in implementing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Kenny, using `AMAZON.EmailAddress` is the best approach here.

Unfortunately you are always going to run into issues with email addresses as an address can effectively be a collection of random characters. If you are expecting a particular pattern of email addresses (such as from your company) then you can create your own custom slot with these examples which might have better luck.